# De-duping users based on membership, level thereof, and expiration date or membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a database with duplicate user records, and I need to pick the "best" user based on a few factors:

1. Users with memberships should be selected before those without
2. Memberships have levels, and all things being equal, the user with the "best" membership level should be selected.
3. Users with active memberships should be selected before users with expired memberships.

Based on those conditions, I came up with something like the following query (actual query is too sensitive).

```
SELECT TOP 1 u.[UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserMemberships] um
        ON u.[UserId] = um.[UserId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Memberships] m
        ON um.[MembershipId] = m.[MembershipId]
    WHERE u.[Email] = @Email
    ORDER BY m.[Order] ASC, um.[Expires] DESC, u.[Created] DESC
```

The problem I'm having is with the ordering of the membership versus the expiration. For example, if there's two duplicate users with memberships of different levels I typically would want the user with the "best" membership level (based on the order), but if that membership is expired, I want the one that isn't expired, even if it's a lower level. However, I can't simply exclude expired memberships, because I need to pick the user with a membership (even if it's expired) over one without a membership.

Essentially, ordering by membership order and then expire date covers most scenarios, but in this one particular case, the order should be expire date, then membership order. What modification could I make to the query to cover this edge-case scenario?

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 WHEN priority 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0... and you can squeeze in any edge case you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? By utilizing a few [`Case`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php) statements to create numeric ranking columns, you can still keep your expired records in the query but assign them a lower value so that the active memberships must be evaluated first:

```
SELECT TOP 1 u.[UserId], 
                Case um.[Expires]
                    When null then 9999      --Inactive Membership
                    When >= GetDate() then 1 --Expired Membership
                    Else 0                   --Active Membership
                End as ActiveRank, 
                Case m.[Order]
                    When null then 9999      --No Membership
                    Else Order               --Membership Ranking
                End as MembershipRank
  FROM [dbo].[Users] u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserMemberships] um
    ON u.[UserId] = um.[UserId]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Memberships] m
    ON um.[MembershipId] = m.[MembershipId]
  WHERE u.[Email] = @Email             
  ORDER BY ActiveRank ASC, MembershipRank ASC, u.[Created] DESC
```

*Note: I wasn't quite sure what you were doing with the `Created` field so I left that in the Order.*

This means that the following holds true:

1. `ActiveRank` will split the ordering into two distinct groups... the top half of the list will be ordered by active memberships and the lower have will be ordered by expired or non-existent memberships.
2. `MembershipRank` will prioritize according to rank (pushing null values or nonexistent memberships to the very bottom of the expired membership portion of the list.

Comment: This is brilliant. One of the chief reasons I couldn't just order by expire date first, is that each value would be unique and would override all the other ordering. It never occurred to me that I could use a case statement in this way to generalize the expire date. Awesome, and seems to work perfectly from my initial testing. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Here is psuedocode for how I would solve this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM (
  SELECT UserId, 1 AS rnk
  FROM Table
  WHERE {most desireable conditions are true}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT UserId, 2 AS rnk
  FROM Table
  WHERE {2nd most desireable conditions are true}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT UserId, 3 AS rnk
  FROM Table
  WHERE {3rd most desireable conditions are true}
  ...
) u
ORDER BY rnk ASC, {Secondary OrderBys like ExpDate etc}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done before is use a case statement to provide a weight to my different factors. Then you can choose what you want to do based on the overall weight. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CASE WHEN Expires >= GETDATE() THEN 10 ELSE 0 END
    +
    MemberLevel --Assuming this is some number that already ranks the member based on level
    +
    CASE WHEN IsMember THEN 2 ELSE 0 END MyRank
FROM [Your tables]
ORDER BY 1 Desc
```